# What info is availble inside the pinfo parameter in a lua tshark listener?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

So I'm looking at how listener taps work. What I've come up with at this point is:

```
my_tap = Listener.new(nil, "myfilter")
myvar = Field.new("something to look at")

-- then the callback
function my_tap.packet(pinfo)
   -- format the time like os.date("%c", pinfo.abs_ts)
   -- what else is in pinfo.???
   -- lots of stuff
end
```

I have been unable to find any thorough documentation on what gets exposed to lua via the pinfo parameter to the packet callback. So far I have found *pinfo.abs_ts*. Which is great because *tcp.options.timestamp.tsval* seems to either be null or contain incorrect / incomplete information all the time.

What exactly gets exposed through pinfo? Is there a list of information I can pull somewhere other than pinfo.abs_ts?

Comment: Looks like I asked too hastily, brain must of been fried yesterday. http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Pinfo.html seems to describe pretty much everything I was looking for.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to this question and accept it, so the question no longer shows up on the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Pinfo.html](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Pinfo.html#lua_class_Pinfo) seems to describe pretty much everything I was looking for

Comment: The link is expired. Can you update the link, or yourself add a description of what information  `pinfo` holds?